# Default gateway setup in different networks connected through intranet service

Tags: networking, routing, gateway

How do I setup default gateway on two different networks connected to a third network (home office) through a provider? the provider provides intranet service. The two sites need access to internet through the third network.
network A - 192.168.1.0/24
network B - 192.168.2.0/24
network C - 192.168.3.0/24
Network C has access to the internet and is to provide internet to the other networks. Each network is connected to the provider through tp-link wireless wifi routers that are configured to connect to the intranet service provided by the provider.

Comment: We need more information regarding the topology, and it is not clear what is the issue and what you want to do